# How to avoid breaking clone/copy method when new fields are added?

Tags: java, clone, deep-copy

I have a simple copy/clone method that is important to my application:

```
  @Override
  public Operation getCopy() {
    Operation copy = new Operation();
    copy.year = this.year;
    copy.stage = this.stage;
    copy.info = this.info;
    copy.user = this.user.getCopy();
    // NOT TO BE COPIED! copy.id = this.id;
    ...
    return copy;
 }
```

Note that there are some specific fields that should not be copied. And some complex objects (like User) that has their own copy method.

The problem is that as new code is developed, sometimes a developer creates a new field that should be copied, but he forgets to add it to the `copy` method:

```
private String additionalInfo;
```

And even though there is not a compilation error, there is a business problem that is only discovered later by our QA team or even by the users.

What can I do to prevent this? I have tried JUnit tests that make comparisons between the original object and its copy, and they work well for existing fields but they do not account for new fields.

Answer (score 2):

I use what I call a "loop and switch" test for this:

```
for (Field field : Operation.class.getFields()) {
  switch (field.getName()) {
    case "year":
      // Test that year is copied correctly.
      // Initialize blah so that year is set.
      assertEquals(getCopy(blah).year, blah.year);
      break;
    case "stage":
      // Test that stage is copied correctly.
      // Initialize blah so that stage is set.
      assertEquals(getCopy(blah).stage, blah.stage);
      break;
    case "id":
      // We don't want to copy id.
      // Initialize blah so that id is set.
      assertNull(getCopy(blah).id);
      break;

    // etc.

    default:
      throw new AssertionError("Unhandled field: " + field.getName());
  }
}
```

It's not a very imaginative name: you loop over all of the fields in the class, and then switch straight away, so that you can handle the individual fields separately and explicitly.

The advantage of this is that the lack of handling of newly-added fields are caught immediately by the `default` case. You get a great big slap in the face to say that you need to handle it in the test - and, by extension, that you need to handle it in the production code too.

The disadvantage when using plain old Java reflection is that it doesn't catch fields being removed. This is maybe a "less bad" situation, as it's just unused code that you're left with, rather than there being untested code paths in the production code.

---

I developed (or read somewhere, I unfortunately can't recall) this idiom whilst building protocol buffer-protocol buffer converters. Java protocol buffers have [generated field numbers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated), so you can actually switch on the field number, rather than the name:

```
for (FieldDescriptor fieldDesc : proto.getDescriptorForType().getFields()) {
  switch (fieldDesc.getNumber()) {
    case FIELD1_FIELD_NUMBER:
      // ...
    case FIELD2_FIELD_NUMBER:
      // ...
  }
}
```

The nice thing about this is that you find out about removed cases too, since the field number will no longer be generated, meaning that the test switch will no longer compile.

Comment: This approach is extremely unstable in the face of changes. It's usually enough to test `assertEquals(copy, original, "copy failed");`.

Comment: @LewBloch except that relies upon `equals` checking all the fields too.

Comment: Only the ones needed to establish equality. If the state is determined by other fields then they _should_ be accounted for in `equals`, et al.

Comment: @LewBloch also, checking with equals can't deal with fields that you intend not to clone, like the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

How come code review missed the lack of an override?

Also, the copy method should not be so brittle. If you have "specific fields that should not be copied" why are they visible to child classes?

Why is the inheritance hierarchy so deep? If every type that needs copying were to implement a `Copyable` interface then it would be much harder to miss the lack of an override during development and you wouldn't need a deep inheritance hierarchy. Those classes that happen to inherit a suitable base implementation of `getCopy()` can call it via `super.` to get started, those that don't simply implement the inherited interface method.

You cannot force programmers to override a method from a concrete implementation via the compiler. Code reviews are supposed to catch such mistakes. If they don't then have a word with the reviewers who missed it.

Implementation of an abstract method is easier to catch because the compiler moans if you don't.